# Specify zone/region in gcloud preview app deploy

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

If I try to deploy my app with `gcloud preview app deploy` i will get a running instance in us-central1.

How do i select the region or zone? My Cloud SQL instance is located in Europe so my App Engine needs to run in Europe too!

I've tried to set it by gclod config but this seems to have no effect:

```
gcloud config list
[compute]
region = europe-west1
zone = europe-west1-b
[core]
account = my@email
disable_usage_reporting = True
project = myproject
user_output_enabled = True
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, the European offering for the App Engine is limited. If you have a Premier account, you can set the location from the console. If not, you have to fill out a request form to have your app hosted in Europe. There are other conditions such as having billing enabled. More info: [Server Location](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/location)